# nanotime: how to deal with NAs in a tibble?

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, biginteger, nanotime

I am using the excellent `nanotime` package to store my timestamps, but I am unable to make the package work when my `tibble` contains a missing value.

Consider this:

```
library(nanotime)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

tibble(time = c('2020-01-01 10:10:10.123456',
                NA,
                '2020-01-01 10:10:10.123456')) %>% 
  mutate(enhance = nanotime(time, 
                            tz = 'GMT', 
                            format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S'))
Error in RcppCCTZ::parseDouble(x, fmt = format, tz = tz) : 
  Parse error on NA
```

What am I missing here? Using `na.rm = TRUE` does not work unfortunately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `NA` is of type logical, you need to have all the values in the column of same type. We can use `as.integer64` to replace logical `NA`'s with `integer64` `NA`.

```
library(nanotime)

tbl <- tibble::tibble(time = c('2020-01-01 10:10:10.123456',
            NA,
            '2020-01-01 10:10:10.123456'))
tbl$enhance <- as.integer64(NA)
tbl$enhance[!is.na(tbl$time)] <- nanotime(na.omit(tbl$time), tz = 'GMT',
                                 format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E9S')
nanotime(tbl$enhance)
```